# Redirecting a URL that contains a question mark

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

It's been necessary to move the position of my blog and I'm trying to make sure I catch all of the links in via the old link and redirect them to the new one.

The blog has been moved from http://example.com/ to http://example.com/blog/

The URLs used to generate with the date before the post name (by default) which I've decided not to do, to keep the URLs memorable.

The issue is that there's a ? character in the original URL (the default URL produced by the CMS I'm using and it's causing problems with the redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^post.php?s=2012-01-01-blog-post$ /blog/blog-post? [R=301,L]
```

So I need to escape the ? somehow but I can't work out how!

I could use a more general redirect that avoids the ? but that would redirect to the listings page, not the article itself:

```
RewriteRule ^post.php$ http://tempertemper.net/blog/? [R=301,L]
```

How do I make it read the ? as part of the URL!?

Thanks for taking a look!

Martin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a RewriteCond to check for the presence of a QUERY_STRING value and then, assuming the query string matches your blog pattern, capture the blog name and then use the captured value in the RewriteRule. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^s=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(.*)$
RewriteRule ^post.php$ /blog/%1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The %1 refers to the first capture pattern in the matching RewriteCond (and the RewriteRule will not trigger unless the RewriteCond is a match).

The reason this is necessary is that a RewriteRule cannot see the query string as part of the request path, so you have to check for (and capture) a query string using a RewriteCond before the RewriteRule.

Comment: You need a `?` at the end of `%1` otherwise the query string gets appended to the end.

Comment: I replaced the $ before the {QUERY_STRING} with a % and used the ? as @jon suggested and it works! Thank you!

Comment: @JonLin Good call. I forgot about the query string being copied to the target URL.